# Dynamics 365 - Tooling or webAPI

Tags: .net, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, xrm

An article is present on MSDN that allows us to decide what development style to use for new Dynamics 365 projects. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602917.aspx#NetOrNot

For our current project we are building a web application that gets data from Dynamics365. Following the flow chart we would thus come to this:

- Code written using .NET? Yes
- Code used in plug-ins, custom workflows, or custom XAML workflows? No
- Project is a Windows client? No

==> Use Web API

We are unsure what the benefit is of using the Web API compared to the XRM Tooling assemblies. From what we see, when using the Web API we need to write the overhead of calling the webservice through a webrequest ourselves.
The XRM Tooling assemblies does already contain this code.

What are the core differences between XRM Tooling assemblies and using the Web API?
Why would there be a difference whether we developing for a Windows Client or a Web Client?

Answer (score 2):

You can use XRM Tooling. It will work with the Web API endpoint. It manages the connection to the old OrganizationService or the new web api endpoint based on the connection string and it should be transparent for you.